# Как открыть новую вкладку перед уже открытой / JS

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в следующем...
window.open('https://google.com') // открываем таким образом вкладку в новом окне, она находится справа от существующего, необходимо чтоб вкладка открывалась слева, перед страницей в которой вызвался этот метод.

Comment: `window.open` открывает новое окно, как именно открывать новое окно задается в настройках браузера из обычного скрипта к ним нет доступа

Comment: Можно открыть старую страницу в новой вкладке, которая откроется справа, а новую - в текущей

Comment: @Darth, а как ты переключишь фокус на новую вкладку, чтобы пользователь не заметил, что у него сайт редиректит на левую страницу? :)

Comment: @Grundy А как ты откроешь новую вкладку, чтобы пользователь не заметил, что у него открылась новая вкладка с левой страницей?

Comment: @Grundy p0rnhub как-то делает )))

Comment: @Darth, например когда пользователь сам открывает вкладу в фоне, при этом вкладка открывается, но пользователь остается в старой. При твоем предложении, его старая вкладка редиректнится куда-то, а что в новой - пользователь еще не знает :)

Comment: @IgorLut, странно :-) не замечал там такого

Comment: @Grundy Да, наверное они так и делают )) Ссылка открывается в новой вкладке, а старая редиректится куда нужно.

Comment: @IgorLut все так